# Comparing 2 variables when one is retrieved from text file

Tags: python, linecache

I am trying to write code that compares variable **b** with value retrieved from text file using *linecache.getline*

The problem is it will never print our "ITS WORKING" because the values never match, even if they do :-(

THE TEXT FILE: In the text file there is **only one** character and its **"a"**

Here is the code:

```
import linecache

b="a" 

a=linecache.getline("TextFile.txt",1)


if a==b:
    print("ITS WORKING")
```

Comment: did you cinsider printing out a?

Comment: what is the content of "TextFile.txt"

Comment: On first line there is "a"

Comment: I printed variable a and it printed "a" so i dont think the problem is there, but i really dont know :-(

Comment: Is it a file that has only `a`, or many characters along with `a`

Comment: Its just single character "a" :-)

Comment: did you try printing the Length of a?

Comment: I  didnt know how to, thx for tip i guess it will help me a lot in future :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to strip the extra spaces at the end of line that is read.

```
a=linecache.getline("TextFile.txt",1).strip()


Keerthana:~ kiran$ cat TextFile.txt
a
Keerthana:~ kiran$ py Desktop/test.py
a
ITS WORKING
Keerthana:~ kiran$
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: it'd be helpful if you could add the contents of the input file in question!

Comment: If thats the case, it works perfectly fine. Kindly cross check!

Comment: LOVE YOU xD. It works like charm, i was stupid i was trying to retrieve the value from txt file with different name, now with .strip() it works great! Thanks!

Comment: Well, i dont have enough reputation to upvote but i will accept it as son as possible but there is 1 min limitation... Accepted now :-)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html), `linecache.getline` will include the trailing newline character, that's why your match does not work.